# Remote control / remote desktop access via Bluetooth and Android app

Tags: bluetooth, remote-desktop

I'm running Arch Linux and using an Android phone (Galaxy S8). My goal is to control my Arch desktop using my phone over Bluetooth. I will be in another room within Bluetooth range, but out of visible sight of the PC monitor.

In particular, I want to control Audacious music player using more than just generic play/pause/previous/next buttons. I would like to see the Audacious UI on my phone to have full control over the music selections.

So far I have tried this client/server pair:

- unified-remote-server on Arch (installed from AUR)
- Unified Remote Full by Unified Intents from the Play Store

The generic "media remote" function works, but it only provides the basic play/pause/previous/next controls.

Is anyone using a Bluetooth Android remote app for full desktop access (similar to vnc)? If not, is there a way to make the VLC remote for Android work over Bluetooth?

Comment: is there a reason that you need to use bluetooth? Wi-Fi might yield better results. KDE connect works very well, even if you're not using plasma.

Edit: just saw that you want something similar to vnc. Unfortunately I doubt that a reliable remote desktop session could be established over bluetooth considering that it can be very slow. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this, few of them are to get the linux remote control apps from the Google PlayStore, and connect with your linux PC using Bluetooth or Wifi. Here are lists of some popular ones:

- [Andro Mouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iandrobot.andromouse.free&hl=en)
- [iWritingPad Keyboard Mouse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iwritingpad.iwritingpad&hl=en)
- [Ultimate Mouse Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.negusoft.ucontrol&hl=en_US)

Comment: Those don't appear to be suitable when you can't see the PC screen.